# Forcing the emitting of the allOf section when using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation.JSchemaGenerator

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I can successfully use the Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation.JSchemaGenerator to generate valid JSONSchema for a given class.  This works fine, **however**, a third party consumer requires that it has a

```
"allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/definitions/ClassName" } ]
```

block of code in the emitted JSON Schema.

I can currently get the output to appear as

```
{
    "$id": "https://xxxxx/classname",
    "definitions": {
        "ClassName": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
```

but I need it to look like

```
{
    "$id": "https://xxxxx/classname",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ClassName"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "ClassName": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
```

Does anybody know what I need to do to achieve this?  There is only one class being referenced.

Currently, I have the generator using code like this:

```
var _jsonSchemaGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
_jsonSchemaGenerator.SchemaIdGenerationHandling = SchemaIdGenerationHandling.None;
_jsonSchemaGenerator.SchemaLocationHandling = SchemaLocationHandling.Definitions;

var schema = _jsonSchemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(T));

console.WriteLine(schema);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide your full schema.

Comment: What third party is requiring it like that? Speculating as to the rest of the schema, I can't think of any reason.

Comment: There is only 1 class in the schema with only a couple of properties.  I agree that there is no normal reason for it to be emitted but I believe that they have a CI process that needs this to be present.

Comment: The reason I ask to see your full schema is because definitions on their own do nothing in terms of JSON Schema. The use of "allOf" that way may not be required.